# WooCommerce product&category import to Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, import, export, woocommerce

I want migrate all product and category data from WooCoomerce to Magento. I have an woocommerce .csv export file, which contains all of necessary data.

How can I convert this csv file to magento import file? 
Here an google docs file which contains magento and woocommerce field names:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JKSUXPttdu4bXUC5SidhBA29vDayW54HkX4yEIlmF6A/edit#gid=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need some tool to convert your CSV to a Magento ImportExport CSV file. You can find details about the specification of those target files at https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/.

Please not thet categories cannot be imported in default Magento. You will need some kind of extra tool for that like AvS_FastSimpleImport (my tool), ApiImport, magmi or uRapidFlow Pro.